# Does Pandas use hashing for a single-indexed dataframe and binary searching for a multi-indexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have always been under impression that Pandas uses hashing when indexing the rows in a dataframe such that the operations like `df.loc[some_label]` is `O(1)`.

However, I just realized today that this is not the case, at least for multi-indexed dataframe. As pointed out in the [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex), "Indexing will work even if the data are not sorted, but will be rather inefficient (and show a PerformanceWarning)". Some articles I found seem to suggest, for multiindex dataframe, Pandas is using binary-search based indexing if you have called `sort_index()` on the dataframe; otherwise, it just linearly scans the rows.

My question are

1. Does single-indexed dataframe use hash-based indexing or not?
2. If not for question 1, does it use binary-search when `sort_index()` has been called, and linear scan otherwise, like in the case of multi-indexed dataframe?
3. If yes for question 1, why Pandas choose to not use hash-based indexing for multi-index as well?

Comment: I'll answer from my experience using >4GB dataframes.
1. No. The loc operation scales badly with size. I wonder why though, it seems like the natural choice.
2. My computations received a huge boost from sorting the index prior, so at least it's a smarter algorithm. I have no clue what happens with multi-indexes though.
3. Null.

Too lazy to write the speed experiments for all of these, but they sound easy to do!